# Как обработать событие "Полная версия сайта" в мобильном браузере Safari

Tags: html, jquery, css, mobile, safari

В мобильном браузере Safari, если зажать кнопку перезагрузки страницы выскакивает кнопка переключения под названием "Полная версия сайта". Вопрос заключается в том, каким образом можно уловить и отработать это событие для того что бы перенаправить пользователя с моб версии на десктоп?

Редирект у меня должен быть реализован след. образом. По нажатию на кнопку мне необходимо удалить куку, а затем перекинуть на другой адрес. Все сводится к тому что я не знаю как отследить событие по браузерной кнопке.

Comment: На андроиде в стандартном браузере тоже вижу в выпадающем меню кнопку "полная версия сайта". Так что вопрос актуален и для андроида

Comment: а удалять куку уже после захода на полную версию сайта не годится?

Comment: вопрос был задан не про куку. Вопрос как обработать событие! у меня мобильная версия на субдомене стоит m.mydomain.com, и если я нажму полная версия сайта то оно просто перезагрузит страницу, а мне нужен редирект на mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Можно при заходе на страницу мобильной версии проверять User-agent header — у Хрома при обновлении страницы в полной версии меняется часть заголовка с `Linux` на `Linux x86_64`, вероятно так же и у Сафари, но надо проверять. А после проверки уже перенаправлять пользователя на по-настоящему полную версию.